# Cypress visiting an URL is not loading content of the site

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, pageload, cypress-intercept

When I set baseUrl and try to visit URL, the content of the URL is not getting loaded.

Here is config file.

```javascript
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'qu3jox',
  e2e: {
    baseUrl : 'https://dxplus.mom.gov.sg',
    pageLoadTimeout : 60000,
    // modifyObstructiveCode: false,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 20000  
  }
});
```

Here is the spec file :

```javascript
describe("Verify identify header",() => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit("/")
  })

  it("verify that How to identify",() => {
    cy.get(elementSelector.masterHeadLink).should('be.visible').contains(' How to identify ').click()
  })
})
```

Here is the Output: Content of the site is not getting loaded

[image: Cypress screenshot]

Console log:

[image: Browser console log]

Network status:

[image: Browser Network tab]

Comment: Can you show the F12 dev console output or the Network tab? I guess the solution is to be found there showing an error about not being able to load some resource.

Comment: Edited the question and added both the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, your answer is probably around that "integrity" SHA.

Answer (score 0):

If the above method doesn't work try to use:

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
```

OR

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
```

To eliminate the "integrity" SHA edit the config below:

```
{
    "experimentalSourceRewriting": true
}
```

Comment: I think `cy.visit('/')` works fine but not sure at what end problem it is. Why content is not getting loaded. When I try it to normal browser it is loading fine.

Comment: I update the anz check it. Otherwise, try to update to new Cypress versions and re-run the packages.

Comment: Tried both the things. None of them worked :(